# Delphi GetTickCount is not a valid integer

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to set a unique id using `GetTickCount`

I am doing the following

```
var
UniqueID : DWORD;
LastUniqueID : DWORD;
uniqueString : string;
begin

UniqueID := GetTickCount;
LastUniqueID := GetTickCount + 1000;

uniqueString  := intTostr(LastUniqueID);//or UniqueID 

end;
```

I got invalid integer value on `uniqueString  := intTostr(LastUniqueID);`

> Project project1.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message
>   ''2312357250' is not a valid integer value'.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I urge you in future to make sure that the code you post matches the error that you report. You did not manage to do that here. Please get into the habit of posting a [mcve] that you have verified. The fact that the code you posted does not match the error message suggests a lack of clarity of thought that is a fundamental block to your progress and development. Slow down and think harder when you face problems. Get your facts clear before jumping to conclusions. Improving your thought patterns will pay dividends.

Comment: If you need a unique ID, why not use [`CreatGUID`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.CreateGUID)?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the electricity were cuts off . i forget to add that i convert back uniquestring to integer again . your answer clear of using int64 helps me thank you .

Comment: It's no excuse. At some point you submitted this misleading question. Please take more care.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have shown code that does not match the error message that you report. Your actual code calls `StrToInt` rather than `IntToStr`. I know this because that error message is produced by calls to `StrToInt` rather than `IntToStr`.

Your code looks more like this:

```
UniqueID := StrToInt('2312357250');
```

Note that `StrToInt` returns a signed 32 bit integer type. Valid values are in the range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Your value is outside the valid range for `Integer`, hence the error.

If you want a simple way to side step all these range issues, then use `Int64` instead of `DWORD` or `Integer`, and call `StrToInt64`.

Furthermore, these lines are troublesome:

```
UniqueID := GetTickCount;
LastUniqueID := GetTickCount + 1000;
```

You make two distinct calls to `GetTickCount`. These two calls may yield different values. Indeed, if `GetTickCount` rolls over, then the second call may return a value that is less than the first one.

Yet more troubles surround `GetTickCount + 1000`. If `GetTickCount` returns a value close to the upper limit, then you will encounter integer overflow, which may have results that you don't expect. Use `GetTickCount64` to avoid that pitfall.

However, I remain to be convinced that the system tick count can is a good way to generate a unique ID. Depending on your requirements, this may well be a poor solution to your problem, whatever it is. On the face of it, your code appears to preclude requesting a unique ID less than a second later than the previous time you requested one. Of course, without knowing your requirements it is hard to recommend an alternative.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the cause for the error, especially because I cannot reproduce it here. The call to IntToStr uses the Int64 overload and thus shouldn't fail with an EConvertError when provided with a DWord value.

Comment: @Uwe You are correct. In fact I was tricked by the fact that the asker provided code that does not match the error message. They actually are calling `StrToInt`. Thank you.

Comment: The overflow issue can be avoided by using [`GetTickCount64()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411.aspx) with `UInt64`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So long as we are happy to rule out a system with uptime of more than  584942417 years .......  ;-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau instead of using gettickcount at all can i use ticks64 in indy ?

Comment: @madammar: you could, though `Ticks64()` is just a wrapper for `GetTickCount/64()` on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 2312357250 is too big. Although it is valid as a DWORD, the hex representation 89D3C582 is equivalent to a negative number, which a DWORD cannot represent, hence the message.

Comment: valid as a DWORD but a DWORD cannot represent?  These answer feels not right.

Comment: There are no negative DWORDs, the hex representation maybe negative for an integer, not for a DWORD.